# How to send multiple array with jQuery in MVC.NET?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have 2 arrays in my Razor view. The first one checked checkboxes and the second is for unchecked. I can send one of them but I don't know how to send both of them. This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#checkAll").click(function() {
        $(".checkBox").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });
    $("#confrim").click(function() {
        var selectedIDs = new Array();
        var unseletedeIDs = new Array();
        $('input:checkbox.checkBox').each(function() {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                selectedIDs.push($(this).val());
            } else {
                unseletedeIDs.push($(this).val());
            }
        });
        var options = {};
        options.url = "/Parts/ConfrimAll";
        options.type = "POST";
        options.data = JSON.stringify(selectedIDs);
        options.contentType = "application/json";
        options.dataType = "json";
        options.success = function(msg) {
            alert(msg);
        };
        options.error = function() {
            alert("Error!");
        };
        $.ajax(options);
    });
});
```

This is the action:

```
  public ActionResult ConfrimAll(int?[] selectedIDs, int?[] unSelectedIDs)
    {
        if (selectedIDs!=null)
        {
            foreach (int id in selectedIDs)
            {
                Part obj = db.Parts.Find(id);
                obj.IsOk = true;
                db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }
        if (unSelectedIDs!=null)
        {
            foreach (int id in unSelectedIDs)
            {
                Part objs = db.Parts.Find(id);
                db.Parts.Remove(objs);
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    return Json("yes"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide both array as part of an object to the `data` parameter of the `$.ajax` call. Try this:

```
$("#confrim").click(function() {
    var data = {
        SelectedIDs: [],
        UnSelectedIDs: [],
    }
    $('input:checkbox.checkBox').each(function() {
        data[this.checked ? 'SelectedIDs' : 'UnSelectedIDs'].push(this.value);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Parts/ConfrimAll',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        },
        error: function(x, s, e) {
            console.log('Error!');
            console.log(x, s, e);
        }
    });
});
```

Note that it's much better practice to provide an object to the `data` parameter as jQuery will then encode it for you to the required format, escaping any special characters as it does it.

Comment: That's not very helpful feedback. In what way did it not work? Did you update the properties of the `ConfrimAll` (sic) method so that the ModelBinder works?

Comment: yes your are right.this the method of confrimall:   public ActionResult ConfrimAll(int[] SelectedIDs, int[] UnSelectedIDs)
       {
            foreach (int id in SelectedIDs)
            {
               Part obj = db.Parts.Find(id);
                obj.IsOk = true;
                db.Entry(obj).State=EntityState.Modified;
            }
            foreach (int id in UnSelectedIDs)
            {
                Part objs = db.Parts.Find(id);
                db.Parts.Remove(objs);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json("yes");
        }

Comment: Ok - the issue was the key names of the object didn't match the parameters of the Action. I've updated my answer for you. If this still doesn't work, check the console for errors.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
JSON.stringify({ selectedIDs: selectedIDs, unseletedeIDs: unseletedeIDs });
```

You should have the two parameters `selectedIDs` and `unseletedeIDs` in the Action filled with this.